# Apply LIMIT only within a part/group of the table

Tags: sql

With the following query

```
SELECT timestamp, movie_rating
FROM Movies
ORDER BY timestamp, movie_rating DESC
```

I have achieved the following table:

[image: Input table]

But I only want to display the top 3 movies *within* each timestamp. I expect the table to look like:

[image: Expected output]

I thought LIMIT would be applied within the (timestamp, movie_rating) specified by the ORDER BY, but if I appply LIMIT 3, I get the following:

[image: My current output]

I'm not sure if I am not aware of some syntax that lets me easily do this

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: I believe MySQL, but whatever engine a solution is in, I can probably translate it to work with mine.


I will try out this solution @kmoser

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution from the suugested stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results/12114194#12114194

seemed to work. This didn't appear under the "do any of these answer your question?" section when I was making my question